# Can father send me the amount of proof of funds required for immigration?

Tags: immigration, canada

I want to immigrate to Canada. My father is willing to give (not borrow but give) money required for it. Will it be ok to take money from him?

Comment: Why not? After the gift it will be your property and you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: @SteffenRoller Canadian immigration specifically states that the money must be the applicant's, not borrowed nor loaned. So it's an issue of proof. Fahad Uddin, possibly having a notarized letter from him, plus some financial proofs that giving you the money is not a hardship for your father.

Comment: @mkennedy Yes, I thought that if somebody has money in his account, under his name, to his disposal then he should be fine. That's what I had to show. Does it matter whether your father, mother, uncle, aunt, cousin, sister or brother gave it to you?

Comment: Oh, I agree, but if immigration is suspicious, they could treat it as funds-parking AKA you got a loan or someone loaned you the money--even a relative.

Answer (score 3):

As is noted, when [proof of funds](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/funds.asp) is required, e.g., express entry:

> You can’t borrow this money from another person. You must be able to use this money to pay the costs of living for your family (even if they aren’t coming with you).
>
> The funds must be available both when you apply and when (if) we issue you a permanent resident visa. You must prove to an immigration officer that you can legally access them to use to settle here when you arrive.
>
> For proof, you must get official letters from any banks or financial institutions where you are keeping money.

Money given to you as a gift can be used for proof of funds. You would want to show the funds in your account for a minimum of three months before you apply.

And, in case you need to satisfy any concerns, have a letter from your father, signed, saying that it is a gift and does not have to be repaid. His statement may need to be accompanied by documents showing from where the funds came (that they were his to give, not a loan to him, and any tax obligations were satisfied).